# How to remove spaces to make a combination of strings

Tags: c#, string

I've been trying to figure out the best approach to combining words in a string to make combinations of that string.  I'm trying to do this for a class project.  If the string is "The quick fox", I need to find a way to output "Thequick fox", "the quickfox", and "thequickfox".  I've tried using string.split and gluing them back together, but haven't had a lot of luck.  The issues is the string input could be of any size.

Comment: Can you show us your current attempts, and where in particular they are failing?

Comment: You will have to output 2^(n - 1) combinations where `n` is a number of words. It will run in feasible time if `n <= 30`. I suggest to take a mask iterator and visit all values from 0 to 2^(n - 1), the you will construct a combination, check `i`-th bit to see if `i`-th space should be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try this for fun. The idea here is to split the bigger problems into smaller subproblems. So I first started with strings that had 0 and 1 space. I see that with 0 space, the only possible combinations is the string items. With 1 space, I can either have that space or not.

Then I just have to recursively divide the problem until I get one of the base cases. So to that do that I `Skip` elements in the split array in increments of 2. That way I am guaranteed to get one of the base cases eventually. Once I do that, I run it through the program again and figure out how to add all the results of that to my current set of combinations.

Here's the code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test1 = "fox";
        string test2 = "The quick";
        string test3 = "The quick fox";
        string test4 = "The quick fox says";
        string test5 = "The quick fox says hello";

        var splittest1 = test1.Split(' ');
        var splittest2 = test2.Split(' ');
        var splittest3 = test3.Split(' ');
        var splittest4 = test4.Split(' ');
        var splittest5 = test5.Split(' ');

        var ans1 = getcombinations(splittest1);
        var ans2 = getcombinations(splittest2);
        var ans3 = getcombinations(splittest3);
        var ans4 = getcombinations(splittest4);
        var ans5 = getcombinations(splittest5);
    }




    static List<string> getcombinations(string[] splittest)
    {
        var combos = new List<string>();
        var numspaces = splittest.Count() - 1;
        if (numspaces == 1)
        {
            var addcombos = AddTwoStrings(splittest[0], splittest[1]);
            var withSpacesCurrent = addcombos.Item1;
            var noSpacesCurrent = addcombos.Item2;
            combos.Add(withSpacesCurrent);
            combos.Add(noSpacesCurrent);
        }
        else if (numspaces == 0)
        {
            combos.Add(splittest[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            var addcombos = AddTwoStrings(splittest[0], splittest[1]);
            var withSpacesCurrent = addcombos.Item1;
            var noSpacesCurrent = addcombos.Item2;
            var futureCombos = getcombinations(splittest.Skip(2).ToArray());
            foreach (var futureCombo in futureCombos)
            {
                var addFutureCombos = AddTwoStrings(withSpacesCurrent, futureCombo);
                var addFutureCombosNoSpaces = AddTwoStrings(noSpacesCurrent, futureCombo);

                var combo1 = addFutureCombos.Item1;
                var combo2 = addFutureCombos.Item2;
                var combo3 = addFutureCombosNoSpaces.Item1;
                var combo4 = addFutureCombosNoSpaces.Item2;

                combos.Add(combo1);
                combos.Add(combo2);
                combos.Add(combo3);
                combos.Add(combo4);
            }
        }



        return combos;
    }

    static Tuple<string, string> AddTwoStrings(string a, string b)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(a + " " + b, a + b);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working, not sure if it is the best algorithm.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        //split the input string into an array
        string[] arrInput = input.Split(' ');

        Console.WriteLine("The combinations are...");

        //output the original string
        Console.WriteLine(input);

        //this loop decide letter combination
        for (int i = 2; i <= arrInput.Length; i++)
        {
            //this loop decide how many outputs we would get for a letter combination
            //for ex. we would get 2 outputs in a 3 word string if we combine 2 words
            for (int j = i-1; j < arrInput.Length; j++)
            {
                int end = j; // end index
                int start = (end - i) + 1; //start index

                string output = Combine(arrInput, start, end);

                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //combine array into a string with space except from start to end
    public static string Combine(string[] arrInput, int start, int end) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool combine = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrInput.Length; i++) {
            //first word in the array... don't worry
            if (i == 0) {
                builder.Append(arrInput[i]);
                continue;
            }
            //don't append " " if combine is true
            combine = (i > start && i <= end) ? true : false;

            if (!combine)
            {
                builder.Append(" ");
            }
            builder.Append(arrInput[i]);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give the case of original string when you have input string as "The quick fox says hi"

Comment: Thanks. I edited it.